# paper jam konica minolta bizhub 4000p

Tags: printer, network-printer, multi-function-printer

The issue is a constant jam output. I have tried to reinstall imaging unit. But it doesn't help. Keep saying Missing or unresponsive imaging unit 31.66.

Comment: Have you tried some different paper? Does it jam with a single sheet? Multiple sheets? From the feed tray only? Have you replaced the drum? When was it last serviced?

Comment: Yes, I have tried different papers. No, when I sent with the multiple sheets.

Answer (score 1):

According to the Service Manual, error 31.66 implies you need to perform a "Cartridge gearbox service check". Try the steps outlined on [page 109](https://www.manualslib.com/manual/1407048/Konica-Minolta-Bizhub-4700p.html?page=109&term=Cartridge%20gearbox%20service&selected=6) of the manual.

If that is not the cause, and as you say it jams with an error message about the imaging unit, remove the imaging unit and check for little scraps of paper in that area. Perhaps use a vacuum cleaner.